# Does xbuf_frurl() supports HTTP_POST?

Tags: api, http-post, g-wan

So far, I've only seen examples of using xbuf_frurl() with HTTP_GET method. Does this function in g-wan support HTTP_POST? If it does, how do I pass in the POST data?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll need the curl library for this kind of request (look at http://gwan.com/developers libraries part)

http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/

and here the g-wan sample

http://gwan.com/source/curl.c

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. Already tried curl - just that it's a bit more lines of code to write.

Comment: Sure, C is very verbose ... Maybe you can use Ruby or something else ?

Answer (score 0):

The `xbuf_frurl()` G-WAN API call can be used with `HTTP_POST` when providing `x-www-form-urlencoded` parameters:

```
xbuf_frurl(xbuf, "gwan.com", 80, HTTP_POST, "/?form", 1000, "&arg1=123&arg2=456");
```

BTW, the next release brings an `HTTPS` flag to use SSL:

```
xbuf_frurl(xbuf, "gwan.com", 443, HTTPS | HTTP_POST, "/?form", 1000, "&arg1=123&arg2=456");
```

Both calls are more concise than libcURL, and doing it in a "less verbose" way (than one line of code) seems unlikely.

Hope it helps.